# How to press physical buttons of android programatically

Tags: android, awtrobot

I want to press volume button programatically. In Java it is possible using the robot class, but in Android there is no robot class.

I am wondering how to achieve this in Android.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you want to simulate the pressing volume button instead of adjusting volume programmatically?

Comment: @Arkadiy m i sure.. 1 sec .. yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to increase/decrease the volume programmatically which would be a tad bit easier, however if you want to use it for some other process then you can check the code below - 
EDIT - The snippet I gave before doesn't work, but this one does. It uses a runnable so the try catch block is necessary.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {         
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                    //This is for Volume Down, change to 
                    //KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP for Volume Up.
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }   
        }).start();
```

Comment: your anwer look great..but i am having exception on
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN);

Comment: Each device uses a standard for the KeyEvent, which in this case is KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN. I am not sure how this is happening. Did you try seeing if it is being interrupted ? Add a Log to the catch block to check that.

Comment: is there a way to hold instead of just pressing button? @pronoobsanved

Comment: @mazhar I wrote an answer about that here, let me know if it works for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551794/how-to-detect-a-long-press-hold-action-on-hardware-keys

Comment: It require  android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS, but the permission only work in rooted device. I am testing in Android version 21. How to solve it

Comment: @user8430 That permission is not needed for this snippet to work.

Answer (score -1):

how about this

```
 private abstract class SimpleButton extends Button {
        public SimpleButton(String text) {
            super(TechDemoLauncher.this);
            setText(text);
            setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onButtonPressed();
                }
            });
        }

        public abstract void onButtonPressed();
    }
```

after that you can just implement the onButtonPressed() method like this

```
private void Example(String string) {
    yourLayout.addView(new SimpleButton(string) {
                @Override
                public void onButtonPressed() {
                    //insert your code
                }
            });
}
```